# When using Grails, are there any advantages to making non-write service methods static

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

I am working on a Grails project, and it seems to me almost all non-write service methods could be turned into a static method. Some coworkers seem to think this is a bad idea due to issues testing, but Groovy's `metaClass.'static'` seems to solve those issues.

So what are the advantages/disadvantages to using static vs. non-static methods in services that do not utilize instance variables?

Comment: Not sure I guess I mean non-write. I could see where a transaction may be desired for a read if you wanted to do optimistic locking on the application side. But I am not a DBA so my terms are probably wrong.

Comment: I would question what kinda of things you have that are well suited to be in static methods but that aside, why would you put the static method in a service?

Comment: Because it isn't using any instance sort of values, since in grails the main CRUD methods are static as well. so for example Object.findAllById(id) this is a static and not in need of instance related variables

Comment: Is there any benefit to defining a method like that in a service artifact?

Comment: Of course there is more logic than that just not anything instance specific. So I was using a service for the additional logic. This was just as simple of an example as I could make it.

Comment: There are numerous benefits to having code like that in an instance method in your service even if they don't access any instance state. For example, caching and transaction management. If you aren't taking advantage of any of that, why do you want to involve a service artifact at all?

Comment: Honestly mainly convention, but can you explain in a little more detail why you can't cache something unless it is an instance object? Seems to me it should be easier to cache a static method than an instance based one but I have little experience here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52055/discussion-between-jackie-and-jeff-scott-brown)

Comment: What you are describing is not consistent with convention. It specifically deviates from convention and for no benefit.

Answer (score 1):

For one you cannot annotate a service method as using a read only transaction if the method is static. If you do not mark a method as read-only using @Transactional and you query objects with GORM the read performance is worse, since GORM dirty checks objects for changes if the transaction is not read-only.

Comment: An interesting side note @Transactional seems to be broken anyway seeing this https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10538 in 2.3.7 still